# Keep Saved IB Historical Data Accurately Adjusted

Tags: historical-data, interactive-brokers, fundamentals, adjustments

How have you dealt with adjusting saved historical data, specifically using the IB API?

As far as I can tell, currently, I need to perform the calculations described on [Quandl's blog](https://blog.quandl.com/guide-to-stock-price-calculation).

I haven't looked closely enough into IB's fundamental data offerings to know if I'll need to get some of those data values from a different source (e.g., Quandl).

What has your experience been with this? Am I approaching this in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, because IB has

- TRADES - data adjusted for splits but not dividends, and
- ADJUSTED_LAST - data adjusted for splits and dividends

I can check what I have saved from earlier that day or the previous day against their data, and compute an adjustment factor for only splits, only dividends, and both.

Using that, I have an accurate daily adjustment factor with minimal additional work.